# how to set default value in hbm.xml of a type "numeric_boolean"

Tags: hibernate, hbm

I'd like to ask how to set the default value in **hbm.xml** of the type `numeric_boolean` please

```
<property name="isSundayToday" column="IS_SUNDAY" type="numeric_boolean" />
```

I tried with `default="true"` or `default="1"`, it didn't work.
Someone can help please?

Comment: You have to set the default value in a nested column tag. Have a look at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-mapping chapters 5.1.11 and 5.1.22